# jQuery draggable position unchanged

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have four draggables next to each other and I want it to be so that once a draggable is remove from the list, the rest would stay in place.

```
<div class="draggables">         
        <div id="d1" class="box">
            first box</div>  
        <div id="d2" class="box">
            second box</div>
        <div id="d3" class="box">
            third box</div>
        <div id="d4" class="box">
forth box</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.draggables{
    width: inherit;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.box{
    width: 180px;
    height: 30px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("#d1, #d2, #d3, #d4").draggable({
        revert: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                top : 0,
                left : 0,                
            };
            return !event;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `opacity` of the "removed" item to `0` to simulate hiding.

Instead of using the `revert` option, you can use `stop` to trigger an action when the mouse is released. Also, you don't need to invoke `draggable` using each individual `id`. You can simply call it on `.box` since all of the `div`s share that class.

In the example below, I'm assigning a class of `hidden`, which sets the `opacity` of the chosen `div`/element to `0`.

**JQuery:**

```
$(".box").draggable({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/6oqowrv3/1/)**